# how can I change allowed file type in codignetor which actually work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller code but only `jpg` and `png` file are uploaded I also changed it my process `model.php` also.

Is there any way to change it? And it doesn’t show any warning. [You can check it from here](http://www.photoclippingbd.com/index.php/login/uploadFlie) but you need to register first...

```
public function saveTestimonial() {
  $config['upload_path'] = './testimonial_photo/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|psd|zip|tif|ai|eps';
  $config['max_size'] = '1024';
  $config['max_width'] = '10240';
  $config['max_height'] = '7680';
```

Comment: have you read the uploading http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

You should declare file upload like the below code. Since you are uploading images, docx, zip files you should not declare max_width and max_height. But you can change the max_size for the file.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = 'testimonial_photo/';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('gif|jpg|png|jpeg|zip|pdf|doc|docx');
    $this->upload->do_upload('filename_in_html_input')
```